# How to nominate a SharePoint 2019 web server as search server?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search, sharepoint-on-prem

My client got 3 SharePoint web servers (SP Web 1, SP Web 2 and SP Search), which they would like two of them to be the Web and application server and one as a search server which performs crawling and indexing function.

The installation order is like this:

First I installed SP Web 1, created the SharePoint farm
After than SP Web 2 is installed and joined the farm
Finally, SP Search

My Idea is like to stop all services except "Search Administration Web Service", "Search Host Controller Service", Search Query and Site Setting Service" and "SharePoint Server Search" in Manage services in this server:

[image]

However, The current problem on the search server is: the "Search Administration Web Service" is in "Stopped" state it can't be start and the "SharePoint Server Search" is also stopped in SP Search. But it is "Started" on the other 2 web servers.

If I force the crawling to start in "Search service application", it stucks at starting. Does anyone have idea why this happens and how to remove the search from the other web servers?

[image]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @CallumCrowley I am using SharePoint 2019

Comment: Why not just use MinRole? If they want high availability for search, add an additional search server. Search services should not be on an FE for performance reasons.

Comment: @TrevorSeward I just tried converting the role to the search server and seems the crawl services started as expected, however surprisingly after checking the logs, I found some policy regarding encryption which was not supported. I followed this guide https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/security/configuration-to-support-kerberos-aes-encryption and it starts crawling...